# How to select a dropdown option in Kendo grid for java selenium automation testing?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, kendo-dropdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvb3X.png)

I am trying to select dropdown option from a grid but unable to find the list of options in code to select from. Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. adding image of HTML code to the post is bad practice no one will write that for you. if they have to debug the problem.